# What does $\Bbb S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ stand for?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $n\geqslant 1,f: \Bbb R^n - \{ 0 \} \to S^{n - 1} \times \Bbb R,x\to(\frac{x}{||x||},\ln(||x||))$ is a homeomorphism which the inverse is $f^{-1}:S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\},(y,t)\to e^{t}y$.

I was reading this example but I cannot understand what $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ means. I suspect that $S^{n-1}$ is the counter dominion of the function. y

**Questions:**

**1)** Is $S^{n-1}$ the counter-dominion of f?

**2)** Why is the counter dominion $S^{n-1}$? Where does the $n-1$ comes from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's obviously a formatting issue here, but I think the intent is that $f$ is a map (actually, homeomorphism) $\Bbb R^n - \{ 0 \} \to S^{n - 1} \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: $S^n$ is the $n$-sphere $\{(x_0, \dots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\, x_0^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = 1\}$. The notation $\S^{n-1}\mathbb{R}$ or $\S^{n-1}$ is presumably just a typo.

Comment: @anomaly I have just corrected the typo.

Comment: I have never heard of counter-dominion, nor did I find anything on Google. Did you mistype something? Perhaps you are talking about domain and codomain? And what is that symbol in the title that never reappears in the body?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^n$ ie 
$$\Bbb S^{n-1} =\{\xi\in\Bbb R^n: \|\xi\|=1\}$$
$n-1$ represent the DIMENSION OF $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ as a MANIFOLD
precisely,
$$\dim \Bbb S^{n-1}= n-1, ~~~~~ \dim \Bbb R^{n} =n$$

For instance, in dimension 2, i.e in $\Bbb R^{2}$
the unit circle is defined
$$\Bbb S^{1} =\{\xi\in\Bbb R^2: \|\xi\|=1\} \equiv \{e^{i\theta}: \theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$$
is of dimension one. $\dim\Bbb S^1 =1$ roughly speaking you see $\Bbb S^1$ as the real line $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Are you saying that $x\to(\frac{x}{||x||},\ln(||x||))$ is a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Where did you read that

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your preocupation. but from what I read on OP question . His problem has nothing do with that map

Comment: Why the author uses $S^{n-1}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Because $S^{n-1}$ and $\Bbb R^m$ are not topologically equivalent.

Comment: He used $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ because $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\|=1$ that is $ \frac{x}{\|x\|}\in S^{n-1}$

Comment: @GuyFsone              Got it! Thanks!